# Modless CMFCPropertySheet with PropSheetLook_OutlookBar parented to a CFrameWnd

Tags: c++, mfc

When I create a modless CMFCPropertySheet with the look set to PropSheetLook_OutlookBar and its parent is a CFrameWnd the window is created correctly but MFC asserts when I close the window.

[Here is the assert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hA3au.png)

From what I gathered, this crash happens in the docking manager (the outlook bar is "docked" to the rest of the PropertySheet) and it’s because the parent window of my CMFCPropertySheet is derived from a CFrameWnd instead of a CFrameWndEx but I cannot change the parent window to a CFrameWndEx because it breaks the rest of the application.

Also the bug happens only when the PropSheetLook_OutlookBar is used.

My question is: Is there a way to use the PropSheetLook_OutlookBar when the parent window is derived from a CFrameWnd? Or am I doing something wrong somewhere?

Thanks you

Comment: Why does it break the rest of the application when you derive from the Ex class? I did that exact change on LOTS and LOTS of projects ... and no application got broken!

Comment: I dont know what I did wrong but I retried converting to CFrameWndEX and the aplication opens now (Before the aplication windows didn't even open and I got loots of Assert everywere). Thank  You for making me try converting to a CFrameWndEx again that fixed my problem.